# In Ruby, perform a function on the contents of a block

Tags: ruby

As a Ruby programming exercise, I'd like to make a function "reverser" which reverse every word of a string. However, it should operator on the contents of a block and not on an argument. So

```
reverser {"hello dolly"}
```

should return "olleh yllod". I know how to make a similar method:

```
def reverse_words(string)
  words=string.split()
  words.map! {|word| word.reverse}
  words.join(" ")
end
```

However, the method should operate on the contents of a block and not on a 'normal' argument. So far I've got this:

```
def reverser(&prc)
  yield.reverse
end
```

However, this only reverses one word and not each word in a sentence. I'm not really sure how to get a 'handle' on the contents of the block passed as an argument in this way. Any ideas?

Comment: Why? Why do you want to do something like this?

Comment: Also, your title is inaccurate. You want to perform a function on the result of a block, not its contents -- the former is possible; the latter (most likely) isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def reverser
  yield.split.map(&:reverse)
end

reverser {"hello dolly"}
 => ["olleh", "yllod"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that one can simply assign a variable to the output of "yield". So I defined

```
def reverser
  str=yield
  words=str.split()
  words.map! {|word| word.reverse}
  words.join(" ")
end
```

The command

```
p reverser {"hello dolly"}
```

Then leads to the desired output.